# Does the jquery success event run asychronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I know that code I run in jquery's implementation of ajax is asynchronous.

My question is, **does the success event of jquery's implemenation of ajax also run asynchronously?**

In other words, if I did some time-consuming operation in the success event, could it potentially freeze up the DOM? Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "longprocess.php",
     type: "post",
     success: function(){
          do_another_very_long_process(); 
    } //will this slow down the DOM?
});
```

Comment: why don't you just try it out?

Comment: `Does it run in the background?` No. JS has only a single thread, so there is no concept of 'the background'. `Would a time-consuming operation freeze the DOM?` Yes it would.

Comment: You can get something like background processing by using WebWorkers.

Comment: @AlexTartan I'm not confident enough in my coding skills yet to know if it wasn't something I was doing wrong. I have tried it out before.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I changed my wording and got rid of the background questions since ajax doesn't run in the background as you replied. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no background code in JavaScript, but I assume you meant asynchronously like Ajax. Yes, it will freeze up the DOM. The function inside the `success` event is called when the Ajax result comes back with no errors, and the code is executed like any normal JavaScript code.

Comment: yes, I got rid of the background parts of my question since they are confusing/incorrect.